# Android classes and persistence

Tags: java, android

I know about [Android data storage options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) and have tried most of them out. But I am not sure how to decide which of those methods would be best for me. I have what I consider a pretty well defined class hierarchy with subclasses, with each class having several member property variables and arrays of other subclasses... on paper. But how do I make it persistent? And keep the object-orientation in tact? For instance, if I have the following class

```
 MyClass
 - private String s1
 - private ArrayList<MySubclass1> subclassList
 - public get/set s1
 - public get/set subclasslist
```

Well, this is great for oo, and I can create getters and setters for the member variables, but they aren't persistent. I'll have to take snapshots of the data at certain times to ensure the data does persist. The other option is to use all database storage and get rid of the private member variables and then just use public methods that read and write from the database. This is great for persistence, but I lose that finely structured object orientation. And that ArrayList gets kind of funky. I will have to do stuff like

```
 MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
 MySubclass1 mySubclass1 = new MySubclass1();
 myClass.AddNewSubclass1ObjectToSubclassList(mySubclass1);
```

instead of

```
 MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
 MySubclass1 mySubclass1 = new MySubclass1();
 myClass.subclassList.Add(mySubclass1);
```

And I would have to write methods for count, remove, indexOf, and all of the other great methods that come with ArrayLists.

So, have I missed something obvious? Am I making this harder than it really is? What is the best way to deal with this?

Comment: Why would your class keep a list of subclasses? And why do you think having getter/setter for every class member is 'great for oo'? Having getter/setter for every member is the same as having every member public which means no encapsulation at all.
Perhaps, you should start from the other end - implement what your program is supposed to do and only after that beautify it.

Comment: Oh, I guess that wasn't clear. No, my class does not keep a list of subclasses. That was supposed to imply a list of objects of the MySubclass1 class. It's not that I think getter/setter is better for oo. Yes, that is the same as having public members. Many of my getter/setters do some logic checks, but I showed that primarily out of habit. My point is, if you are storing directly to a database, you lose the awesome functions of an ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

For convenience you can use some object serialization library, e.g.:

- Object to XML Marshaling - [Simple XML serializer](http://simple.sourceforge.net/)
- Object to JSON Marshaling - [Google Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)

Then you can persist the result of marshaling in a file in order to restore your objects later. I think [Internal Storage](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal) is best way for this.

Comment: Wow, I had never heard of that. It certainly looks like a working solution, it looks a little difficult to learn. I am going to look it over though in case I don't come up with a different solution.